# linux command to empty all files of a directory

Tags: linux, file, command

I´d like to empty all files from a directory. I´d tried this:

```
find myFolderPath/* -exec cat /dev/null > {} ';'
```

but it does not work. How can I do it?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You can't use redirection (`>`) within `find -exec` directly because it happens before the command runs and creates a file called `{}`. To get around this you need to do it in a new shell by using `sh -c`.

Also, note that you don't need to `cat /dev/null > file` in order to clobber a file. You can simply use `> file`.

Try this:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '>"{}"' \;
```

Comment: I found find . -type f -exec sh -c '>"{}"' \; to be working better.

Comment: Was getting error "sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('" because of some filenames with special characters, changed the command to find . -type f -exec sh -c '>"{}"' \;

Comment: Another improvement, according to [SC2156](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2156), the command should become something like `find . -type f -exec sh -c '>"$1"' shell {} \;` to prevent special characters in file names from being executed as part of the script

Answer (score 16):

This will do what you want:

```
for f in *; do >$f; done
```

Comment: I like it, but it breaks when spaces in filename.

Comment: How to run this one as `sudo` ?

Comment: Great solution. Worth noting: you want to ensure that you're in the CORRECT folder when doing this. It will execute on all files in the folder you are currently in.