# Linux is it possible to empty the contents of all files in a directory

Tags: linux

Is it possible in a single command (no loop) to clear the contents of each file in a directory?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid loops?

Comment: Would a well crafted AWK or Bash command be considered a programming question?

Comment: i want a single command to run from command line.  I'm sure there is some way to do it with fine -type f -exec echo "" .....  just cant complete it

Comment: @MartyWallace: you can type in (or paste) loops on the command-line too

Comment: Yes, but its not nice i dont think

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564850/linux-command-to-empty-all-files-of-a-directory

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use truncate:

```
truncate -s 0 directory/* &> /dev/null
```

Comment: It works with wildcards, unlike `cat /dev/null` ... `truncate -s 0 /var/logs/*.log`

Answer (score 13):

This is ugly as hell, but it works:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'echo -n "" > $1' sh {} \;
```

This will clear every file in every subdirectory.

To just clear the files in the current directory:

```
for i in *; do cat /dev/null > $i; done
```

(Yes, it's a loop, but it's one line.)

Comment: I found that [this](https://gist.github.com/qaisjp/8871c717ec300d704ae3) was good for me, but you might want to change the printf output to ""

Also, `echo -n ""` actually put `-n` in each file.

Comment: `echo -n "" ` is unnecessary; `'> $1'` will do.

Comment: beautiful! :-D :-p